# Buenas noches comunidad, como hago para poner el evento keyup en un textbox en visual fox pro 9.0

Tags: eventos, teclado, visual-foxpro

como hago para poner el evento keyup en un textbox en visual fox pro 9.0, quiero que al momento de escribir y despues dejar de hacerlo suceda un evento el cual me realice la validacion de los valores del campo, recuerdo que esto ya lo hice en asp .net y lo realize con el keyup, pero para visual fox pro no ubico este evento en las propiedades del text box. atento a su respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes utilizar en VFP para las cajas de texto son lo métodos GotFocus, LostFocus, que se realizan cuando recibe el foco y cuando lo pierde. Para validar usas el Valid.

Otro que puede servirte es el método When que sucede justo después de cuando el control recibe el foco.